# XAML (Metro app) - how to delay a FadeInThemeAnimation by a second

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a Grid containing a ProgressRing in my XAML which fades into view when the app is performing a long-running task:

```
        <Grid Height="100" Width="100"  >
            <Grid Background="#55000000" />
            <ProgressRing x:Name="mapProgressRing"  Width="50" Height="50" Foreground="White" />    
        </Grid>
        </Border>
```

However, I want to delay the animation by 1 second, the idea being that if the task finishes in less than a second, the Grid is never displayed.  Thus avoiding the grid constantly flickering on and off when very short tasks are performed.

However, despite setting BeginTime in the XAML, above, the Grid always begins fading into view immediately, even when I try this in code.  Here's my code:

```
    void dataSou_WillStartFetchingSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Don't bother fading in spinner unless it takes more than a second
        showSpinner(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
    void Instance_WillEndFetchingSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hideSpinner();
    }

    #region Spinner
    void showSpinner(TimeSpan? delayStartTime)
    {
        // Stop animation in case it's already running
        mapRingFadeOutStoryBoard.Stop();
        // Fade in, delaying the start by the specified time
        mapRingFadeInStoryBoard.BeginTime = delayStartTime;
        mapRingFadeInStoryBoard.Begin();
    }
    void hideSpinner()
    {
        // Stop the 'fade in' animation in case it's still running
        mapRingFadeInStoryBoard.Stop();

        // Fade out
        mapRingFadeOutStoryBoard.Begin();
    }
    #endregion
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's wrong, but you could use async/await instead. Just mark your method as async and then do "await Task.Delay(1000)" to wait for a second before starting the animation.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause all sorts of potential concurrency issues?  e.g. if showSpinner() was called multiple times?

Comment: If you want to wait for a second regardless of what you are doing you are at a risk of potential concurrency issues. Unless you would simply stop the main thread for a second, but the APIs to do that are fortunately not available in WinRT as that is just bad experience. It's a brave new world in which you need to learn how to cope with concurrency issues. :)

Comment: I had imagined that the in-built Storyboard Begin, Stop, etc. methods would already be designed to be both thread-safe and deal with these concurrency issues, do you not think?  In which case, I'm just saying it would therefore seem a better approach to try and work with what's there (if possible) rather than re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Whatever works best for you. I use async everywhere these days.